# How to get data from Unity-based app to third-party Android app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm going to build a third-party app that reads ranking data from a Unity-based game. It seems there is an app with a similar feature, Hearthstone Deck Tracker. Hearthstone is a Unity-based game, and Deck Tracker reads data like cards, logs, results, etc. I'm curious about how can I read data from the app without actual permission because It's a third-party app. I want to make it read a JSON file from the app in background mode, then load it in when it starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hearthstone Deck Tracker (PC) is open source, and you can find it on GitHub:
https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker

The app has gotten quite big over the years, so you can check one of the oldest commits, where the core functionality still exists, but in a way simpler form.
[Version 0.1.1](https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/tree/6e6fc8273f2e7e0ab337cf8fd721370b9d776f41/Hearthstone%20Deck%20Tracker)

Apparently, Hearthstone logs most of its game actions, and the tracker just reads them. I assume it works similarily on Android.

So unless the game you're trying to build an app for logs data like HS, I'm afraid it will be very difficult to do.

Comment: Exactly. Everything was logged in Android/data/com.blizzard.wtcg.hearthstone/files/Logs. In my case, there was not even a single log file in the game's folder. So It seems impossible to get a match data from the game. Now I gotta start a new project... Thanks for the answer.